# Azure SQL Server System Databases

Tags: sql-server, azure

Goal: I need to create a msdb on my Systems Database.

Why: I am trying to move an application database to Azure so multiple computers can connect to it. I created a bacpac file and was able to upload my database, but when I try to connect to the Azure database from the application it won't let me because "msdb..backupset is not supported on this version of SQL Server."

Problem: Azure's SQL Server only has master in its Systems Database. Why does it only have master? How can I get msdb and the others there as well? Do I need a VM?

Comment: Azure does not have, never has, likely never will, have the MSDB or MODEL databases.  Recreating it won't help either.  Also, if you haven't noticed, you can't join two Azure DBs - you only work in one or another.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @SQLMason . Why doesn't Azure have this? Do you have any recommendations on how to proceed then? Should I try something different?

Comment: AzureDBs are just SAAS databases.  If you want all of the functionality of SQL Server, you need a VM with SQL Server installed.  AzureDB != SQL Server

Answer (score 2):

> Problem: Azure's SQL Server only has master in its Systems Database. Why does it only have master? How can I get msdb and the others there as well? Do I need a VM?

yes you need a VM or SQLAZURE managed instance*(which is same as on premises sql server with SQLAgent,clr,...,but with high available capacity of SQLAZure)

The reason why you don't have system databases is ..SQLAZURE is database as service and you just pay for the database you used

*Currently in preview,expected to be GA by the end if this year